# How to add SKSpriteNode from nsarray at runtime without the frame rate going down

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

What i'm trying to do is create all the sprites i'll need for a level before the gameplay starts, so I don't have too many sprites at once.

I split them into 4 arrays, each array corresponds to a section of level, the level being divided into 4 sections.

So when the player crosses over to a section of level the scene adds all the sprites.
This almost works perfect except there is a slight ,sometimes big drop in the frame rate when the scene adds the array's sprites.

Is it possible to add sprites at runtime without affecting the frame rate?

Here is some pseudo code to explain what i'm trying to do.

in SpriteClass.m

```
        _sprite = [[Sprite alloc] init];

        _sprite.position = location;
        _sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5,.5);
        _sprite.zPosition = 5;

        _sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:      
        CGSizeMake
        (_sprite.size.width, _sprite.size.height / 4)];
        _sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        _sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
        _sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCFloor;
        _sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PCPlayerCategory;
        _sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = PCPlayerCategory;
        _sprite.name = @"sprite";


if (_sprite.position.x < 4000) {
[[Singleton shared].spriteArray1 addObject:_sprite];

} 


else if (_sprite.position.x > 4000 && _sprite.position.x < 8000) {
[[Singleton shared].spriteArray2 addObject:_sprite];

}


else if (_sprite.position.x > 8000 && _sprite.position.x < 12000) {
[[Singleton shared].spriteArray3 addObject:_sprite];

} 


else if (_sprite.position.x > 12000) {
[[Singleton shared].spriteArray4 addObject:_sprite];

}
```

in MyScene.m

spawnBox is the rect the player intersects with to let the game know which section the player is in.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

spawnNum = 1;
[self spawn];


}

return self; 
}


-(void)spawn {

switch (spawnNum) {
case 1:

        for (int x = 0; x < [Singleton shared].spriteArray1.count; ++x) {
           [myScene addChild:[[Singleton shared].spriteArray1 
            addObject:_sprite];  objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

         spawnBox = CGRectMake(3500, 0,32,  _tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height);
         ++spawnNum;

 switch (spawnNum) {
 case 2:

        for (int x = 0; x < [Singleton shared].spriteArray2.count; ++x) {
            [myScene addChild:[[Singleton shared].spriteArray2 
            addObject:_sprite];  objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

         spawnBox = CGRectMake(3500, 0,32,  _tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height);
         ++spawnNum;

  switch (spawnNum) {
      case 3:

        for (int x = 0; x < [Singleton shared].spriteArray3.count; ++x) {
            [myScene addChild:[[Singleton shared].spriteArray3 
            addObject:_sprite];  objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

         spawnBox = CGRectMake(3500, 0,32,  _tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height);
         ++spawnNum;

 switch (spawnNum) {
    case 4:

        for (int x = 0; x < [Singleton shared].spriteArray4.count; ++x) {
            [myScene addChild:[[Singleton shared].spriteArray4 
            addObject:_sprite];  objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

        spawnBox = CGRectMake(3500, 0,32,  _tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height);
        ++spawnNum;

    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Also I'm testing on iphone 5c, 6, iPad air, 1st gen ipad mini.

Comment: you should create the sprites ahead of time and reuse them rather than creating new ones on the fly (comparatively slow, especially if the textures haven't been preloaded)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I do create them all before, I just call addChild as needed.  The addChild is what causes the drop.  I was thinking maybe because its too many addChild calls at once. Perhaps delaying them a bit would help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement deleting sprites which are no more visible? 
And you can try add new sprites smoothly. I mean add not whole section at once but add some part of your level section while level moving.

Comment: @LetaOn I've tried allocating new sprites as needed, thats causes a big frame rate drop. I cant delete none visible sprites because they are needed in case the player backtracks.

Comment: Then you can do it on both sides. Add map dynamically. For example add 3 screen sizes. Current screen, 1 screen left and 1 screen right. And then when you move 1 of them remove from scene and 1 new add to the scene.